Get data from SQL database using DbSet
I have the following DataBaseContext:
    modelBuilder.Entity<Artist>()
        .Property(a => a.Name)
        .IsRequired();

    modelBuilder.Entity<AlbumType>()
        .Property(a => a.Type)
        .IsRequired();

    modelBuilder.Entity<Album>()
        .Property(a => a.Title)
        .IsRequired();
    modelBuilder.Entity<Album>().HasOne(x => x.Artist);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Album>().HasOne(x => x.AlbumType);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Album>().HasMany(x => x.Songs);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Song>()
        .Property(a => a.Title)
        .IsRequired();
    modelBuilder.Entity<Song>().HasOne(x => x.Artist);

In my service:
var album = await unitOfWork.AlbumRepository.GetByIDAsync(id);

try
{
    _context.Entry(album).Reference(a => a.Artist).Load();
    _context.Entry(album).Reference(a => a.AlbumType).Load();
    _context.Entry(album).Collection(a => a.Songs).Load();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}

return album;

And in my UnitOfWork:
public virtual async Task<TEntity> GetByIDAsync(object id)
{
    return await dbSet.FindAsync(id);
}

Now when I want to display the details of an album, I want to display the songs. This is working fine.
But I'm not getting the details of the artist for the song. Can anyone help me?

This question is similar to: .NET Core - Entity framework - FindAsync does not return related tables. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In my service I've added the following:
foreach (var song in album.Songs)
{ 
    _context.Entry(song).Reference(s => s.Artist).Load();
}

This works. I'm just not sure if it's the correct way of working.

You could try as in your answer above but maybe following would do the trick aswell
    public virtual async Task<Album> GetByIDAsync(object id)
{
    return await dbSet
        .Include(a => a.Artist)
        .Include(a => a.AlbumType)
        .Include(a => a.Songs)
            .ThenInclude(s => s.Artist)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Id == (int)id);
}

Afterwards your Methodcall could look like this
var album = await unitOfWork.AlbumRepository.GetByIDAsync(id);

if (album == null)
{
    throw new Exception("Album not found");
}

return album;

Basically what ThenInclude does is: It works like a Include but is better suited for more related Data. To read more Information take a look at Using Include vs ThenInclude
Especially Vijayanath Viswanathan's Answer in case my code breaks. I did not test it.
